# How to find full name & path of a program pinned to the taskbar?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

Windows 10.  Suppose I have several versions of a particular application installed.  One of those versions is pinned to the taskbar.  How can I determine the full name and path of the file that would be executed by the version that's pinned to the taskbar?

Answer (score 1):

Check `C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`, and the shortcuts are exactly what gets executed when you click on them. You can also apply commandline arguments in the icon's Properties settings to change the taskbar icon's behavior when clicked.